# Is there a better way to implement the Midpoint Circle Algorithm using the image 0.18 crate?

Tags: algorithm, rust, geometry

I'm trying to implement a Midpoint Circle Algorithm in Rust.
I've rewritten the [C code from Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Midpoint_circle_algorithm#C_example) into Rust syntax.

I got into trouble in the "put pixel" part, firstly I've created:

```
let mut pixel = buffer.get_pixel_mut(x0 + x, y0 + y);
```

then gave it rgb value

```
pixel.data = [red, green, blue];
```

and tried to do same thing with next pixel

```
pixel = buffer.get_pixel_mut(x0 + y, y0 + x);
```

and so on;

The problem is I'm trying to borrow `buffer` multiple times in the same scope, so I created a scope for each pixel assignment. It works, but the code looks awful. Is there a better way to do this?

The full function:

```
fn draw_circle(
    x0: u32,
    y0: u32,
    radius: u32,
    buffer: &mut ImageBuffer<Rgb<u8>, Vec<u8>>,
    red: u8,
    green: u8,
    blue: u8,
) {
    let mut x: i32 = radius as i32;
    let mut y: i32 = 0;
    let mut err: i32 = 0;

    while x >= y {
        {
            let pixel = buffer.get_pixel_mut(x0 + x as u32, y0 + y as u32);
            pixel.data = [red, green, blue];
        }
        {
            let pixel = buffer.get_pixel_mut(x0 + y as u32, y0 + x as u32);
            pixel.data = [red, green, blue];
        }
        {
            let pixel = buffer.get_pixel_mut(x0 - y as u32, y0 + x as u32);
            pixel.data = [red, green, blue];
        }
        {
            let pixel = buffer.get_pixel_mut(x0 - x as u32, y0 + y as u32);
            pixel.data = [red, green, blue];
        }
        {
            let pixel = buffer.get_pixel_mut(x0 - x as u32, y0 - y as u32);
            pixel.data = [red, green, blue];
        }
        {
            let pixel = buffer.get_pixel_mut(x0 - y as u32, y0 - x as u32);
            pixel.data = [red, green, blue];
        }
        {
            let pixel = buffer.get_pixel_mut(x0 + y as u32, y0 - x as u32);
            pixel.data = [red, green, blue];
        }
        {
            let pixel = buffer.get_pixel_mut(x0 + x as u32, y0 - y as u32);
            pixel.data = [red, green, blue];
        }

        if err <= 0 {
            y += 1;
            err += 2 * y + 1;
        }

        if err > 0 {
            x -= 1;
            err -= 2 * x + 1;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because as a request for improvement (since the code works) it is better suited for [codereview](https://codereview.stackexchange.com).

Comment: why not use the method `put_pixel()` ???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know Rust, but you can do something like:

```
while x >= y {
    for xsign in [-1,1] {
        for ysign in [-1,1] {
            {
                let pixel = buffer.get_pixel_mut(x0 + xsign*x as u32, y0 + ysign*y as u32);
                pixel.data = [red, green, blue];
            }
            {
                let pixel = buffer.get_pixel_mut(x0 + xsign*y as u32, y0 + ysign*x as u32);
                pixel.data = [red, green, blue];
            }
        }
    }
```

If Rust gives an easy way to say `for dx,dy in ( (x,y), (y,x) )`, that would let you combine the last two into a single loop using `x0+xsign*dx` and `y0+ysing*dy`.

In Python, you could then consider using itertools.product to combine three for loops into a single for loop that takes `xsign,ysign,(dx,dy)` from the cartesian product `[-1,1]x[-1,1]x((x,y),(y,x))`.  In Python, this would end up being:

```
while x >= y:
    for xsign,ysign,(dx,dy) in itertools.product([-1,1],[-1,1],((x,y),(y,x))):
        let pixel = buffer.get_pixel_mut(x0 + xsign*x as u32, y0 + ysign*y as u32);
        pixel.data = [red, green, blue];
```

I don't know Rust (have I made that clear yet?), but I'd be surprised if Rust didn't have similar mechanisms.